# El sitio móvil no permite el inicio de sesión

Tags: bug, estado-completado, web-móvil

No permite el inicio de sesión en [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) cuando se accede a través de un dispositivo móvil.

Testeado en un Lumia 735.

[image: sitio movil de es.stackoverflow.com]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto ya debe de estar resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Esperemos hasta después del primero de diciembre.  El sitio no se ha lazado al beta todavía, cosa que afectará la manera en que se puede usar con los dispositivos.